# Getting "No type was found that matches the controller named 'SampleSlashBaseService'" when trying to use WebAPI

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, attributerouting

I have a webapi project with a base ApiController named SlashBaseService:

```
[RouteArea("uBase")]
public abstract class SlashBaseService : ApiController
{
}
```

The resulting dll is used in a WebForms project so I also have a WebActivator class with the following code to generate routes:

```
RouteTable.Routes.MapHttpAttributeRoutes(config =>
{
    // Get all services inheriting from SlashBaseService
    foreach (var assembly in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
    {
        foreach (var type in assembly.GetTypes())
        {
            if (type.IsSubclassOf(typeof(SlashBaseService)))
            {
                // Scan assembly
                config.ScanAssembly(assembly);

                // Skip the remaining types in this assembly
                break;
            }
        }
    }
});

RouteTable.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultBase",
    routeTemplate: "base/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });
```

I also have a testservice in a separate assembly:

```
public class SampleSlashBaseService : SlashBaseService
{
    [GET("TestOpenMethod")]
    public string GetTestOpenMethod()
    {
        return "Hello anonymous!";
    }

    [GET("Echo/{message}")]
    public string GetEcho(string message)
    {
        return message;
    }
}
```

All pretty simple stuff. The problem is when I try to go to one of the urls this generates i get the following message:

> No type was found that matches the controller named 'SampleSlashBaseService'.

The route list from /routes.axd also looks correct.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Found the problem.

`ApiControllers` class names need to be suffixed with "Controller", and mine was not.
Changing it to `SampleSlashBaseController` solved the problem.

NOTE:
It is possible to suffix it with "Service" as I did, but then you have to implement a custom `IHttpControllerSelector` like described here: http://netmvc.blogspot.no/2012/06/aspnet-mvc-4-webapi-support-areas-in.html

Comment: I did something along the opposite lines. I had Controller where it wasn't supposed to be! `defaults: new { controller = "APIController" }` should be `defaults: new { controller = "API" }` You must OMIT `Controller` in your `WebApiConfig.cs`!

Comment: That's what happened to me where I left the Controller suffix on the WebApiConfig.cs. Your comment helped me :)

Comment: I was pulling my hair out before I found this. What a silly error to make. THANK YOU

Comment: Stupid as it might sound: Make sure that you suffix it with `Controller`, not `Controlller`! Just spent 30' wondering what on earth is going on...

Comment: i really wish that frameworks didn't make stupid opaque requirements about how classes are named

Comment: you saved my day! :P

Answer (score 11):

You also need to make sure the Controller class is **Public**

Comment: this question is already answered however my comment was the answer for the issue I had. I had the same error however I was missing Public. I wanted to leave this here in case it would help someone else.

Answer (score 6):

In my case the Controller was defined properly, but was not marked public.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, there were two controllers with the same name, in different folders. Renaming them solved the problem instantly.

Answer (score 2):

For what it's worth, I ran into this and my problem was my manually-added class wasn't inheriting from ApiController. The class definition needs to be `public class QueueController : ApiController` not `public class QueueController`. What a dumb thing to overlook.

Comment: Thank you! This helped me. I was inheriting from System.Web.Mvc.Controller, but I wanted to be inheriting from System.Web.Http.ApiController.