# Api Controller Method not calls

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have MVC project, I have added one API controller.in this API controller I have created methods in it.but when I am trying to call this API from postman or localhost with "http://localhost:10133/api/BedfordBrownstoneApi/GetAgentId?username=dgsdgsdgsd&password=sdgsdgs" Url its gives following response.

```
{
  "Message": "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:10133/api/BedfordBrownstoneApi/GetAgentId?username=dgsdgsdgsd&password=sdgsdgs'.",
  "MessageDetail": "No type was found that matches the controller named 'BedfordBrownstoneApi'."
}
```

My API controller is like following.

```
 public class BedfordBrownstoneApi : ApiController
    {
        // GET api/<controller>
        public int GetAgentId(string username,string password)
        {
            DataContext db = new DataContext();
            var data = db.Set<AgentLogin>().Where(a => a.UserName==username && a.Password==password).SingleOrDefault();
            return data.AgentId;
        }
}
}
```

My WebApiConfig class is like following.

```
  public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}",
                defaults: new { action = "GetAgentId" }
            );
        }
    }
```

Comment: try this - remove the 'Api' from controller name  http://localhost:10133/api/BedfordBrownstone/GetAgentId?username=dgsdgsdgsd&password=sdgsdgs

Comment: Is there a `GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);` call inside your `Global.asax` file?

Comment: You didn't mention Controller in your api controller name, check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11384552/getting-no-type-was-found-that-matches-the-controller-named-sampleslashbaseser

Comment: Change your controller class name to 'BedfordBrownstoneApiController'

Comment: @RK_Aus I did this change and call with "http://localhost:10133/api/BedfordBrownstoneApiController/GetAgentId?username=dgsdgsdgsd&password=sdgsdgs" url but same issue

Comment: @SanjivRajput - You have missed the call 'config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();' in WebApiConfig also. I have updated the detail in my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

```
 config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { action = "GetAgentId",id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
```

add Id parameter in your routeTemplete in webapiconfig.

Answer (score 0):

Check Below Question that that similar problem as yours.

Check Accepted Answer of 'Benoit74B'. It clearly explains problem in details. Actual problem is regarding parameters you are passing -

["No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI" here?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24769379/why-is-it-that-no-http-resource-was-found-that-matches-the-request-uri-here)

Answer (score 0):

Remove "API" from  controller name BedfordBrownstoneApi.

Change it from

http://localhost:10133/api/BedfordBrownstoneApi/GetAgentId?username=dgsdgsdgsd&password=sdgsdgs

to

http://localhost:10133/api/BedfordBrownstone/GetAgentId?username=dgsdgsdgsd&password=sdgsdgs

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled attribute routing in api config? config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

With your current route, you should hit it via query string "http://localhost:10133/api/BedfordBrownstoneApi/GetAgentId?username=dgsdgsdgsd&password=sdgsdgs" and decorate the parameters with `[FromUri]`

```
   [HttpGet]
   [Route("api/BedfordBrownstoneApi/GetAgentId/")]
   public int GetAgentId(string username,string password)
   {  
      //api stuff
   }
```

or to hit the api via route parameters - http://localhost:10133/api/BedfordBrownstoneApi/GetAgentId/yourusername/yourpassword

```
   [HttpGet]
   [Route("api/BedfordBrownstoneApi/GetAgentId/{username}/{password}")]
   public int GetAgentId(string username,string password)
   {  
      //api stuff
   }
```

Hope this helps you. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues.

1. Controller name - Change the name, add Controller in the name (BedfordBrownstoneApiController).
2. You missed calling 'config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes()' in Register function.

Please update your 'Register' function in 'WebApiConfig' as below.

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}",
        defaults: new { action = "GetAgentId" }
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have just change my code to following and now its work.

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "BedfordBrownstoneApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}",
        defaults: new { action = "GetAgentId" }
    );
}
```